# how to get selected row data AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get selected rows from table in AngularJS, but not able to figure out how to do that. Below is the plunker to see what I did.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/APb0MeK5th7z79l32SEy?p=preview
```

Code Html

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<table>
<tr><td>Select Column</td><td>id</td> <td>name</td> <td>address</td> <td>classA</td> <td>classB</td></tr>  
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.address}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.classA"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.classB"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" name="save" value="submit">
```

Code JS

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {




    $scope.employees = [
        { id:"1", name: "A",              address: "A1",    classA: true,  classB: true  },
        { id:"2", name: "B",            address: "A2",    classA: false, classB: true  },
        { id:"3", name: "C",            address: "A3",    classA: true, classB: false  },
        { id:"4", name: "D",             address: "A4",   classA: false, classB: true  },
        { id:"5", name: "E",             address: "A5",   classA: false, classB: true  },
    ];  

    });
```

I want the rows which are selected by user from left column check box while they click on submit.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TDJmGqztPLpVHIjQzcSK?p=preview).

```
<td><input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="employee.checked"
       ng-true-value="1" 
       ng-false-value="0"></td>
```

...

```
<button ng-click="getSelected()">getSelected</button>
```

...

```
$scope.getSelected = function () {
  var ar = $scope.employees.filter(
    function (value) {
      if (value.checked == 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    );

  console.log(ar);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind this checkbox to a model, like you did with classA and classB.

for example:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model=employee.selected></td>
```

Comment: After binding a check box what should I do ? Do I need to loop it ? I want only selected employees like if I select 1 and 3 then.